# From R formula to PHP

Tags: php, r, math, regression

So, i have this formula here:

```
model <- gam(inb ~ s(x))
g.hat <- model$fitted
```

Where actually the inb is a two dimensional vector and

```
x <- rbinom(psa, n, progress)
```

Could someone help me to translate it mathematically so i can transform it to PHP then?

Thanks

Comment: Try http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stats-rand-gen-ibinomial.php

Comment: Hi Andrie, thanks, well actually, my main concern is not the binomial distribution, rather than the gam function actually

Comment: Which `gam()`? There are at least 2 that I know of. You'd be better off either arranging to call R from PHP or you could use the original GAM compiled code and call that from PHP. Beyond that, the mathematics are not so much the issue but implementing the algorithm that will fit the additive model. This is non-trivial, with many statisticians researching algorithms to do this robustly and which have good properties.

Comment: the problem is i don't want to use R, what i need is to do in PHP what i do in R, because i need to build an interface

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it will become a lot of work to explain it mathematically.
If you look up the functions by typing them in your R session and hitting return you will see what happens behind the screen. So just type in `gam` for example and hit return. You will see the code which you can translate to php. That would be a lot easier than translating it to maths and then back to php.

Comment: Ahhh, okay, great, thanks :)
will do that!

Comment: You'll need to look at the C code or other compiled language (depending on which `gam()` is being looked at. The guts of the computations are there, *not* in R code.

Comment: yes you are right, but for someone not familiar to c and only willing to translate it to PHP I think its easier to look at the R code, don't you think so?